# Database access with multipe instances

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mariadb

**Description**

I have multiple instances of an ASP.Net Core application, which uses one MariaDb database.

The multiple instances are replicates of the same ASP.Net Core application to realize horizontal performance scale.

The application has a some writes (100 writes / second) to the database, where it is necessary to check unique constraints over two colums in one table.

We can add these constraints to the database itself, in a stored proc or in the application with EF Core.

**Example**

For exmaple, we start a transaction, query some data to check the constraint, write the data and commit the transaction. We do it 100 times in total per second from the different instances of the application.

**Questions**

1. Is it a common way to check these constraints in the application with ef core?
2. Can we get trouble, like inconsistency or interrupted records with this approach?

Comment: A SQL database usually officially supports constraints like the foreign key. Like this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp Usually, you don't have to check the data with C#. I guess the best practice for you is to use a pure-database layer transaction instead of checking it via C# code.

Comment: @Anduin thanks for your answer. The check statement is very helpful, but in my case I need to check an unique constraint about multiple colums. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bulk of any SQL instruction is overhead (network, parsing, optimizing, etc), minimize the number of queries.

If, on the other hand, this leads to added complexity, then that advice may be counter-productive.

If it suffices to have two `UNIQUE` indexes on the table, then do that.  That keeps it down to a single SQL, not the multiple-statement ideas you propose.

The check for "dup key" after trying the `INSERT` is not a round-trip to the server, so it is cheap.

It almost sounds like `INSERT IGNORE` would suffice.

If you need a transaction for proper data integrity in a multi-threaded app, then, by all means, use such.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table(s) and the write statement(s). Also, is it using HDD or SSD drive? There are many optimizations that may let it do much more than 100/sec. But we can't give you a useful answer without discussing specifics.  It is unclear whether "multiple instances" means that multiple threads hitting a single table, multiple threads hitting multiple tables, or even multiple instances of MariaDB (in VMs or Dockers) on a single server.

Some things to speed up:  IODKU, Batched inserts, artificially adding BEGIN+COMMIT, etc.